# Importing files from different folders with relative paths in the code

Tags: python

So, I have a following file structure:

```
main.py
├── net
    └── src
        ├── file.py
        └── dataset
            └── image.jpg
```

I use `import net.src.file` to import `file.py` into `main.py`, that part works.
A function in `file.py` needs the `image.jpg`. However, for some reason, it can't utilize relative path, i. e. `open("dataset/img.jpg")`, it needs the full path, as if we were going from `main.py` - `open("net/src/dataset/image.jpg")`.

Can I import a file and use its functions and force those functions to get a path from their respective directory? (Not `root` but `src`)

I don't want to just give it the path from `main.py`, because I would have to redo a lot of functions, the code is basically a combination of two codebases (It tries to use `file.py` as a library).
Functions work fine when executing `file.py` standalone, but when imported from `main.py` it gives the error - `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: open("dataset/img.jpg")`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "However, for some reason, it can't utilize relative path" It *is* using a relative path. A path that *isn't* relative - i.e., that is *absolute* - would start with a `/` (or a drive letter, depending on the operating system). However, when you use a relative path to open a file, it is only ever relative to the *current working directory* of the *process* that is running - not any particular source code file. Also, *none of this has anything to do with* "importing", or the `import` keyword in Python.

Comment: However, all is not lost. Please see the linked duplicate. Python can tell you a relative path from the current working directory *to* the source code file, and you can use this to locate the resource file.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems the linked duplicate has what I need!